# How are Operating Temperature Bands Determined?

Tags: components, temperature

Manufacturers like [Maxim](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/military/temp-range.cfm), [Altera](http://www.altera.com/devices/common/ind/ind-temp.html#notes), and many more seem to adhere to a commonly defined range of temperatures for applications. For instance,

- Full military (-55°C to +125°C)
- Automotive (-40°C to +125°C)
- AEC-Q100 Level 2 (-40°C to +105°C)
- Extended industrial (-40°C to +85°C)
- Industrial (-20°C to +85°C)

What is the rationale behind these ranges? Are they just an aggregate of temperatures that these applications usually operate in? Or are they calculated using a formula of some kind? Who came up with these?

Comment: The military(US) has a standard that specifies operating temp ratings for electronics, so I would expect companies use that when determining military specs. I would expect the same with automotive, auto companies probably have min/max specs and companies like Altera base their ratings to cover that range. Most likely not a secret formula so much as: military needs devices to operate up/down to set worst case temps, make standard/ask for those specs, companies make military rating to cover said standard/specs. Aka simple supply/demand. Would be interesting if I was wrong though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All those Temperature Ranges are standards. Some defined by some authority, some just common consent. For example AEC-Q100 is the temperature range you have to expect in the internals (not motor room!) of a car. In Winter of Northern Countries you may have temperatures as low as -40°C. Your Car has to work without problems there. 105°C apply to a Car parked in a hot area in direct sunlight.

I expect that the 125°C max in many applications is also determined by material. 125°C is the maximum allowed temperature for most semiconductors.